# Bypass field errors in Google's Place API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, axios, google-api

I am doing some experiments with Google's place API (the search-place function in particular). It seems that certain field options are not provided for certain locations (for example, price_level is not provided for CN Tower). If I try to access the fields in this case

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?
input=CN%20tower
&inputtype=textquery
&fields=price_level
&key=KEY
```

It would return to me the field error:

```
{
  "candidates": [],
  "error_message": "Error while parsing 'fields' parameter: Unsupported field name 'price_level'. ",
  "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

where no other information is provided in the output.

As this error is dependent on the location (i.e. the error won't occur if the location does offer price_level), how can I bypass the field so that whenever it does not exist, the other fields can still be outputted